# writing a recursive method into a non recursive (java)

Tags: java, recursion

I'm a little bit confused as to understanding how recursion works.

Basically I have to replace recursive methods with non recursive methods.

For example, this is the recursive method:

```
public Key min() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return min(root).key;
}

private Node min(Node x) {
    if (x.left == null) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return min(x.left);
    }
}

public Key max() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return max(root).key;
}

private Node max(Node x) {
    if (x.right == null) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return max(x.right);
    }
}

public Key floor(Key key) {
    Node x = floor(root, key);
    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return x.key;
    }
}

private Node floor(Node x, Key key) {
    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        return x;
    }
    if (cmp < 0) {
        return floor(x.left, key);
    }
    Node t = floor(x.right, key);
    if (t != null) {
        return t;
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}

public Key ceiling(Key key) {
    Node x = ceiling(root, key);
    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return x.key;
    }
}

private Node ceiling(Node x, Key key) {
    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        return x;
    }
    if (cmp < 0) {
        Node t = ceiling(x.left, key);
        if (t != null) {
            return t;
        } else {
            return x;
        }
    }
    return ceiling(x.right, key);
}
```

And this is my attempt of doing it non-recursively:

```
public Key min() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return min(root).key;
}

private Node min(Node x) {

    while (x.left !=null){
         x = x.left; 
    }
    return x;
}

public Key max() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return max(root).key;
}

private Node max(Node x) {
    while (x.right!=null){
        x = x.right;
    }
    return x;
}

public Key floor(Key key) {
    Node x = floor(root, key);
    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return x.key;
    }
}

private Node floor(Node x, Key key) {
    if (x == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        return x;
    }
    if (cmp < 0) {
        while (x.left != null){
            x = x.left;
            if (x ==null){
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    Node t = x.right;
    while (x.right != null){
        x = x.right;
        if (x == null){
            return null;
        }
    }
    if (t != null){
        return t;
    }
    else{
        return x;
    }
}
```

I'm just asking if I have the right idea.

Comment: 1. Links invalid 2. you should post code directly in your post.

Comment: A recursive method calls itself. An iterative does not.

Comment: The links you've provided don't appear to work. It looks like it's because they include the SO citation brackets at the end. The code should still be posted here regardless.

Comment: Moved code into SO, and fixed speling :-)

Comment: "Im just asking if I have the right idea" Yes.

Comment: Second one is recursive too, floor function calls floor()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have the right idea.

```
private Node min(Node x) {
    if (x.left == null) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return min(x.left);
    }
}
```

This is good non-recursive solution of the function above.

```
private Node min(Node x) {

    while (x.left !=null){
         x = x.left; 
    }
    return x;
}
```

You should take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming, particularly Memoization.

Edit: Also take a look at similar thread: [Way to go from recursion to iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration)